# Image processing Glamour filter in iphone

Tags: iphone, image-processing, filter, uiimage

I want to create an app in which i want to do some image processing. So I would like to know if there is any open-source image processing library available? also I would like to create a filter like this one [Glamour Filter](http://glamour-filter.en.softonic.com/) any help regarding this would be very much appreciated. If someone already have a source code to create sepia,black and white rotate scale code than please send. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Here is the code for sepia image

```
-(UIImage*)makeSepiaScale:(UIImage*)image
{
    CGImageRef cgImage = [image CGImage];
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(cgImage);
    CFDataRef bitmapData = CGDataProviderCopyData(provider);
    UInt8* data = (UInt8*)CFDataGetBytePtr(bitmapData); 

    int width = image.size.width;
    int height = image.size.height;
    NSInteger myDataLength = width * height * 4;


    for (int i = 0; i < myDataLength; i+=4)
    {
        UInt8 r_pixel = data[i];
        UInt8 g_pixel = data[i+1];
        UInt8 b_pixel = data[i+2];

        int outputRed = (r_pixel * .393) + (g_pixel *.769) + (b_pixel * .189);
        int outputGreen = (r_pixel * .349) + (g_pixel *.686) + (b_pixel * .168);
        int outputBlue = (r_pixel * .272) + (g_pixel *.534) + (b_pixel * .131);

        if(outputRed>255)outputRed=255;
        if(outputGreen>255)outputGreen=255;
        if(outputBlue>255)outputBlue=255;


        data[i] = outputRed;
        data[i+1] = outputGreen;
        data[i+2] = outputBlue;
    }

    CGDataProviderRef provider2 = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, myDataLength, NULL);
    int bitsPerComponent = 8;
    int bitsPerPixel = 32;
    int bytesPerRow = 4 * width;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider2, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef); // YOU CAN RELEASE THIS NOW
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider2); // YOU CAN RELEASE THIS NOW
    CFRelease(bitmapData);

    UIImage *sepiaImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef); // YOU CAN RELEASE THIS NOW
    return sepiaImage;
}
```

Comment: For those looking for this now, iOS 5 and higher, you can apply directly the built-in SepiaTone CIFilter to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for Black & White effect

```
 - (UIImage*) createGrayCopy:(UIImage*) source {

    int width = source.size.width;
    int height = source.size.height;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate (nil,                              width,
                                                height,
                                                  8,      // bits per component
                                                  0,
                                                  colorSpace,
                                                  kCGImageAlphaNone);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    if (context == NULL) {
        return nil;
    }

    CGContextDrawImage(context,
                       CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), source.CGImage);

    UIImage *grayImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)];
    CGContextRelease(context);

    return grayImage;
}
```

Comment: The code you have posted for black & white is actually gray effect. I need code for actual blank & white effect. I have posted the code for sepia filter.

Answer (score -3):

Search for OpenCV

Comment: OpenCV is a face detection library. It's not a Image filter. I am lokking for a image Filter library