# Sepia in Camera Preview View

Tags: iphone, camera

So I've set up a basic live camera preview view (based on apple's own code from the dev center) and I am now looking for a way to add a nice sepia effect to the live feed.

Is this at all possible? I know it'll be processor and memory heavy but the app is only for iPhone 4, the latest iPod Touch and the iPad 2.

Thanks,
Roy

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to add filters to camera preview View..But for sepia I think this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549396/image-processing-glamour-filter-in-iphone) link will be helpful.

Also you will have to go through pixel by pixel. This [thread](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/11158-share-your-image-proccessing-filter-code.html) goes through image processing in detail..One good enough to bookmark..