# sepia version of any NSImage

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage

I am looking for a simple and efficient way to give a special tint to any icon contained in an NSImage. My initial need id to have sepia icons but if  can use other colors it is better.

Do you have any idea to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Regards,

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117211/how-would-i-tint-an-image-programatically-on-the-iphone/1118005#1118005) (though it's for the iPhone) will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will have take image pixel by pixel and adjust rgb values to get the effect.

```
-(UIImage*)makeSepiaScale:(UIImage*)image
{
    CGImageRef cgImage = [image CGImage];
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(cgImage);
    CFDataRef bitmapData = CGDataProviderCopyData(provider);
    UInt8* data = (UInt8*)CFDataGetBytePtr(bitmapData); 

    int width = image.size.width;
    int height = image.size.height;
    NSInteger myDataLength = width * height * 4;


    for (int i = 0; i < myDataLength; i+=4)
    {
        UInt8 r_pixel = data[i];
        UInt8 g_pixel = data[i+1];
        UInt8 b_pixel = data[i+2];

        int outputRed = (r_pixel * .393) + (g_pixel *.769) + (b_pixel * .189);
        int outputGreen = (r_pixel * .349) + (g_pixel *.686) + (b_pixel * .168);
        int outputBlue = (r_pixel * .272) + (g_pixel *.534) + (b_pixel * .131);

        if(outputRed>255)outputRed=255;
        if(outputGreen>255)outputGreen=255;
        if(outputBlue>255)outputBlue=255;


        data[i] = outputRed;
        data[i+1] = outputGreen;
        data[i+2] = outputBlue;
    }

    CGDataProviderRef provider2 = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, myDataLength, NULL);
    int bitsPerComponent = 8;
    int bitsPerPixel = 32;
    int bytesPerRow = 4 * width;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider2, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef); // YOU CAN RELEASE THIS NOW
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider2); // YOU CAN RELEASE THIS NOW
    CFRelease(bitmapData);

    UIImage *sepiaImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef); // YOU CAN RELEASE THIS NOW
    return sepiaImage;
}
```

Code is shamelessly copied from this  [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549396/image-processing-glamour-filter-in-iphone) thread , and it talks about applying sepia filter to UIImage instead of NSImage, but logic can be reused..Also [this](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/11158-share-your-image-proccessing-filter-code.html) thread is one of the best when it comes to image processing..One to bookmark..

**Edit**: As Josh Caswell pointed out, Core Image can be used to create sepia image and some image filtering..So easier method should be to use core Image...Read his answer on how to do it..This method works fine too, especially in iphone where there is no coreImage framework..

Comment: There's no need to do this by hand. CoreImage is more than equal to the task.

Comment: Correct Josh..I am unfamiliar with MAC development.Edited my answer..It is a pity CoreImage is not present in iphone..

Comment: Now core Image is on iphone.. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html

Comment: The OP asked for an NSImage (AppKit) version.

Answer (score 6):

CoreImage has [built-in filters](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH203-TPXREF101), one of which is [CISepiaTone](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000136-SW69), that you can easily use to transform the colors and other aspects of your image.

The steps you need to follow are laid out in [Processing an Image](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH203-BAJDDCEE):

Get a `CIContext` object. The simplest way may be to ask the current `NSGraphicsContext`.

Get a [CIImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/CIImage) representation of your image. This cannot be created directly from an `NSImage`; you will probably want to convert your `NSImage` to a `CGImageRef` using `CGImageForProposedRect:context:hints:` (you can pass `NULL` for the `proposedRect` argument).

Create the filter object, set its values, and get the processed image.

Finally, draw the image in your `CIContext`.