# Apply filter effects to UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I have a image & I want to apply some filter effects on it.
Effects like sepia,sharpen,brightness,RGB colors,Contrast,Grayscale effect according to slider value changed. How to do this?
If any one knows then share some amount of code.
I got lots of solution on it but not obtain the solution on slider value changed.
I want to apply all above filters using slider value changed.

Comment: CoreImage is available in iOS5+ , there are many useful effects available in CI. but only in iOS5+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YOu have to do it manually, there's no kind of "effect" in iOS.

Luckily, you have a lot of awesome code here!

[Image processing Glamour filter in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549396/image-processing-glamour-filter-in-iphone)